# Html in swt treeviewer

Tags: java, html, swt

Is there any way to put HTML into my SWT `TreeViewer`? I want my `LabelProvider` `getText()` String to be interpreted as HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `TreeViewer` does not support HTML.

You can do things like bold or italic text by using a label provider based on `StyledCellLabelProvider`.